# Which conda-build CDT package provides the `X11/X.h` file?

Tags: x11, conda-build

I've got this `requirements:build` section in my `meta.yaml` file:

```yaml
requirements:
  build:
    - {{ compiler('c')   }}
    - {{ compiler('cxx') }}
    - {{ cdt('libx11-devel') }}  # [linux]
    - cmake
    - git
    - swig
    - xorg-xproto  # [linux]
```

But, my build is failing with:

```
  In file included from /home/dbanas/miniconda3/conda-bld/enable_1678986918786/_build_env/x86_64-conda-linux-gnu/sysroot/usr/include/X11/Xutil.h:53,
                   from kiva/agg/src/x11/agg_bmp.cpp:12:
  /home/dbanas/miniconda3/conda-bld/enable_1678986918786/_build_env/x86_64-conda-linux-gnu/sysroot/usr/include/X11/Xlib.h:44:10: fatal error: X11/X.h: No such file or directory
```

**Which CDT package provides the `X11/X.h` file?**

Answer (score 0):

Found it: `xorg-x11-proto-devel`

Now, does anyone know which package provides: `GL/gl.h`?
**==> `mesa-libgl-devel`**

And, in general, is there a map available somewhere?